# Pyspark - ranking column replacing ranking of ties by Mean of rank

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions, ranking

Consider a data set with ranking

```
 +--------+----+-----------+--------------+
 |    colA|colB|colA_rank  |colA_rank_mean|
 +--------+----+-----------+--------------+
 |      21|  50|          1|             1|
 |       9|  23|          2|           2.5|
 |       9|  21|          3|           2.5|
 |       8|  21|          4|             3|        
 |       2|  21|          5|           5.5|      
 |       2|   5|          6|           5.5|       
 |       1|   5|          7|           7.5|     
 |       1|   4|          8|           7.5|     
 |       0|   4|          9|            11|    
 |       0|   3|         10|            11|  
 |       0|   3|         11|            11| 
 |       0|   2|         12|            11|
 |       0|   2|         13|            11|
 +--------+----+-----------+--------------+
```

`colA_rank` is a normal ranking, while with `colA_rank_mean` I would like to resolve ties by replacing the ranking with the mean rank of the ties. Is it achievable with a single pass and some particular ranking method ?

Currently I am thinking of 2 passes but that would seem to require ordering the dataset twice on `colA`, one without partition and one with partition.

```
#Step 1: normal rank
df = df.withColumn("colA_rank",F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("colA")))
#Step 2 : solve ties :
df = df.withColumn("colA_rank_mean",F.mean(colA_rank).over(Window.partitionBy("colA"))
```

Comment: I think it's necessary to have two separate passes through the data as you suggested.

Comment: Is there a ranking operation that combine the two. As far as I see it, it's like the combination of normal rank and **dense_rank**, only that this **dense_rank** use the result of normal ranking. My dataset is huge and this operation is repeated for every feature, I would want to optimize as much as possible. Doing 2 times sort seems costly.

Comment: @Kenny do you want both `colA_rank` and `colA_rank_mean` in the output?

Comment: Nope, @pault. I can afford to lose **colA_rank**. Final **colA_rank_mean** is good enough.

Comment: While we're at it, just a passing thought if we have to keep multiple passes. Do you think the following approach is more efficient, although it seems more steps :  1/ **colA_rank**, then 2/ **colA_dense_rank**, then 3/ instead of **partitionBy("colA")**, use partition by **colA_dense_rank**. My theory is that dense_rank at this time would be integer-based, hence less costly for partitionBy("an-integer-column"), than sort and partitionBy("a-column-with-decimal-precision") ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what  you're trying to do. Why isn't dense rank sufficient for you? Why are the last five entries in `colA_rank_mean` all the same value (`11`)? I think it would be helpful if you could explain why you're doing this as well- there may be alternative methods.

Comment: For ties, I am taking the mean of the normal rank, instead of assigning the **dense_rank**. Ties for value 9 has rank 2, 3, so mean rank is 2.5. Ties for 0 have ranks from 9-13, hence mean rank is 11. This is trying to replicate the strange ranking process in SAS. Don't ask me why SAS did it that way. It's always a mystery :)

Comment: Any comments on the solution ?